# ¿Cómo hacer un Query en SQL con dos Id's diferentes?

Tags: php, ajax, modal

El primer `ID` es del usuario logueado y el segundo es del usuario seleccionado.El del usuario logueado lo voy a imprimir en una variable `Javascript`(usando `JQuery`) y `Ajax`,asi:

```
var idlogueado = <?php echo $myid;  ?>
```

Y el segundo `ID` lo llamo desde un enlace

Al final lo que quiero hacer es cuando hago clic en el enlace es abrir  un modal.Todo eso me funciona y puedo manejarlo bien.

Problema

¿Cómo hacer una consulta con esos dos id que he pasado al modal?

Algo asi;Mi tabla

```
-------   -------    ----------    ---------    --------   --------
ID      nombre      apellido     correo       password    Fotos
------    ------     ---------     --------     --------    ------
```

**JQuery**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){

   $(document).on("click", ".btnopmkgft", function () {

   $('#pocosss').html('<input id="amount" placeholder="busca a alguien a 
   quien donar." type="text" name="howmuch">')




   $('#pocossss').html('<input type="range" name="amountInput" 
    id="amounttogive" value="24" min="1" max="5" 
    onchange="getvalor(this.value);" oninput="howmuch.value = 
     amountInput.value">')



   var userinsession = <?php echo $my_id  ?>;
   var getuser = "getuser.php";
   var userid = $(this).attr('data-clickablecard');

    var Userid = '&userinsession=' + userinsession + '&userid='+ userid  ;


   alert(Userid);


   $.ajax({

    url:getuser,
    data:Userid,
    type:'POST',
    beforeSend:function(){

      $("#jota").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw margin-
       bottom"></i>');
     },

    success:function(result){

      $("#jota").html(result);
    }

    });


    })

     });



   </script>
```

Archivo **GetUser.php**

```
<?php

 include("conexion.php");

  ?>


  <?php

   $user_session_id = $_POST["userinsession"];
   $getuser = $_POST["userid"];

   $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT 
          nombre,
          apellido,
          Id,
          Fotos 

          FROM personas 



   WHERE Id  IN ($user_session_id , $getuser ) LIMIT 2") or die('Error: ' . 
   mysqli_error($conn));


     while ($posts_filas2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
          $id_user = $posts_filas2['nombre'];



if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {?>

    <div class="wr_favs">
     <div class="_alblos">

      <img width="50px"  height="50px" src='<?php  echo 
        $posts_filas2["Fotos"];  ?>'>

         </div>

  <span>200</span>
    <br>
   <div class="_albloss">
   <span style="font-size: 16px;color: steelblue;"><?php echo 
   $posts_filas2["nombre"].' '.$posts_filas2["apellido"];  ?></span><br>




    </div>

 </div>

  <?php

   }

  else{?>

   <div><h2>No hay nada</h2></div>
   <?php
   }



  }

   ?>
```

Comment: Pues se me ocurre que lo mandes por Ajax tus dos ID´s al momento de dar click en el Modal o en algun boton del modal.

Comment: @M.Gress Ese no es problema.Es la consulta con dos Id's

Comment: ¿Y como tienes tu tabla donde quieres consultar?

Comment: @M.Gress He editado y añadido mi tabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno supongamos que tu consulta va a ser algo así:

```
$id_logueado;
$id_enlace;

$query = "SELECT * FROM mi_tabla WHERE ID IN ($id_logueado,$id_enlace)";
```

Podria ayudarte este enlace: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: Gracias hermano!

Comment: Disculpa amigo todo me funciona,pero no en el orden que yo quiero.me gustaría que me saliera el usuario mio(la foto y el nombre)del lado izquierdo y el otro del lado derecho en el modal.He intentado todo con css.y nada!.Pienso que es mejor armar dos código ajax aparte para que me salga bien.Crees que eso esta bien.?

Comment: No le veo nada de malo, pero podrias postear tu código donde recibes la respuesta del ajax para ver como lo podemos acomodar.

Comment: Ok.Lo voy a añadir